# Schema mismatch for label column 'Label': expected Single, got Vector<Single> (Parameter 'labelCol')

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, ml.net

I'm trying out the ML.NET nuget package and experimenting with the different normalization options for regression and prediction trainers. My code is working perfectly when I use Single values (float) but I saw that there were bunch of normalization options that only seemed to work using a vector of Single values so I made the switch and I'm now getting this error when I changed all of my float values to a float array. Am I just missing something obvious?

I'm using ML.NET 3.0.0-preview.23266.6 for this example

```cs
var trainingCount = 50;
var modelInputList = new List<ModelInput>();
var estCount = valuesList.Any() ? valuesList.First().ValueList.Count : 0;

for (int j = 0; j < estCount; j++)
{
    var modelInput = new ModelInput();

    var actual = j < estCount - 1 ? actualList[j] : 0;
    modelInput.Actual = new float[] { Convert.ToSingle(actual) };

    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
        var rvItem = Convert.ToSingle(valuesList[k].ValueList[j]);

        switch (k)
        {
            case 0:
                modelInput.Input1 = new float[] { rvItem };
                break;
            case 1:
                modelInput.Input2 = new float[] { rvItem };
                break;
            case 2:
                modelInput.Input3 = new float[] { rvItem };
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    modelInputList.Add(modelInput);
}

var firstHalf = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(modelInputList.Take(trainingCount));
var secondHalf = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(modelInputList.Skip(trainingCount));
var dataProcessPipeline = mlContext.Transforms
                    .CopyColumns("Label", nameof(ModelInput.Actual))
                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeBinning(outputColumnName: nameof(ModelInput.Input1)))
                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeBinning(outputColumnName: nameof(ModelInput.Input2)))
                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeBinning(outputColumnName: nameof(ModelInput.Input3)))
                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", nameof(ModelInput.Input1),
                        nameof(ModelInput.Input2), nameof(ModelInput.Input3)));
var trainer = mlContext.Regression.Trainers.OnlineGradientDescent();
var trainingPipeline = dataProcessPipeline.Append(trainer);
var trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(firstHalf); // getting the exception here
var trainingData = trainedModel.Transform(firstHalf);
var predictions = trainedModel.Transform(secondHalf);

public class ModelInput
{
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    [VectorType(1)]
    public float[] Actual { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(1)]
    [VectorType(1)]
    public float[] Input1 { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(2)]
    [VectorType(1)]
    public float[] Input2 { get; set; }

    [LoadColumn(3)]
    [VectorType(1)]
    public float[] Input3 { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE: I have included the NormalizeBinning documentation since people don't seem aware that it can handle vectors of single or float values

[image]

Comment: What is valueCount?

Comment: @jdweng Oh sorry I left that out. valueCount is 3

Comment: your code seems to be only filling each array with a single value. Check if the length of rvItem/ModelInput is greater than 1.

Comment: @Nooby-Noob The rvItem is always a single float

Comment: That may be your problem - it is trying to normalize the values within each array, but it is impossible to normalize a single value.

Comment: @Nooby-Noob So the rvItems are being added to a collection of single arrays of the float items. Again my code works fine when using a regular float variable but the issue is converting these floats to a known vector size of float values

Answer (score -1):

There are two issues with your data structure that is causing your problem, firstly normalization requires a set of numbers to act on and secondly, your Label column needs to be a float, not an array of float.

The trainer is expecting each row of data to be a simple vector, with one element being the "Label" and the rest features.

If you want to normalize the features *within* each case, then this will work:

```
 var dataProcessPipeline = mlContext.Transforms
                .CopyColumns("Label", nameof(ModelInput.Actual))                  
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", nameof(ModelInput.Input1),
                    nameof(ModelInput.Input2), nameof(ModelInput.Input3))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeBinning("Features")));
```

If you want to normalize each feature separately - *across cases in the dataset* - you can do this:

```
var dataProcessPipeline = mlContext.Transforms
                .CopyColumns("Label", nameof(ModelInput.Actual))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeBinning(nameof(ModelInput.Input1))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeBinning(nameof(ModelInput.Input2))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeBinning(nameof(ModelInput.Input3))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", nameof(ModelInput.Input1),
                    nameof(ModelInput.Input2), nameof(ModelInput.Input3))))));
```

Both these require the Input Model to look like this:

> ```
> public class ModelInput {
> [LoadColumn(0)]
>
> public float Actual { get; set; }
>
> [LoadColumn(1)]
>
> public float Input1 { get; set; }
>
> [LoadColumn(2)]
>
> public float Input2 { get; set; }
>
> [LoadColumn(3)]
>
> public float Input3 { get; set; } }
> ```

Comment: I really don't understand why you are posting an exact copy of the previous answer which I responded to and will repeat myself here that according to the documentation that normalization supports single values, double values, or a fixed vector of either singles and doubles and the Output or Label in this case needs to be the same type for it to work. Your answer is what I already did and specifically stated this in my op

Comment: I think what you're really not understanding is the basic concepts of normalisation and data structures.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're encountering is likely due to the incorrect usage of the normalization transformations in your pipeline. Specifically, you're applying the **NormalizeBinning** transformation to vectors, which is not what it's designed for.

In your **dataProcessPipeline**, you are applying **NormalizeBinning** to vector columns (**Input1**, **Input2**, and **Input3**) which are already arrays of floats. The **NormalizeBinning** transformation is intended for single float values, not arrays or vectors.

To normalize vector columns in ML.NET, you should use the **NormalizeMinMax** or other similar normalization transformations that are suitable for vectors. Here's how you can modify your pipeline:

```
var dataProcessPipeline = mlContext.Transforms
    .CopyColumns("Label", nameof(ModelInput.Actual))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax(outputColumnName: nameof(ModelInput.Input1)))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax(outputColumnName: nameof(ModelInput.Input2)))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax(outputColumnName: nameof(ModelInput.Input3)))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", nameof(ModelInput.Input1),
        nameof(ModelInput.Input2), nameof(ModelInput.Input3)));
```

In this modification, I've replaced **NormalizeBinning** with **NormalizeMinMax**, which is suitable for normalizing vector columns. Please make sure you're using the appropriate normalization transformation for your data.

Additionally, make sure that the shape and structure of your input data (**modelInputList**) are compatible with the modifications you've made to the pipeline. If you're normalizing vector columns, each column in **modelInputList** should be an array of floats.

Remember, the choice of normalization method should depend on the characteristics of your data and the requirements of your machine learning model.

Comment: I went ahead and updated my post to show that NormalizeBinning does support singles, floats, or vectors of single or float values in the documentation as do many other normalization options. So what I'm trying to do in my post should be possible according to the ML.Net documentation